# How to merge two MySQL queries together

Tags: php, mysql

How can I merge the following queries together?

To get all the objects of a particular type I use

```
SELECT ID FROM social_objects  
WHERE subgroup='23' ORDER BY time_created DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have this search too, for titles

```
SELECT ID FROM 'social_objects_single' 
WHERE 'title' LIKE '%indian%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How can I get only objects of subgroup 23 with certain titles?

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: You need to tell us what's the relationship (common key) between social_objects and social_objects_single

Comment: The table social_objects contains the id's of all the social_objects like users, blogs etc.. The table social_objects_single contains the complete information about these objects. So inorder to do a search, I have to club these two tables together and get the ID back from them.

Comment: social_objects_single and social_objects are they connected what is the foreign key

Comment: I notice you have this in your SQL : `WHERE subgroup='23'`. Are you sure the column data type is NOT integer?

Comment: The common key for both is ID.

Comment: Field names are delimited by backticks (\`), not single quotes (').

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : the subgroup is always a numeric value

Comment: Therefore your query should be `WHERE subgroup=23`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `social_objects_single` has the same `ID` as the `social_objects` table you could do this:

```
SELECT so.ID FROM social_objects so 
INNER JOIN social_objects_single soi ON soi.ID = so.ID
WHERE so.subgroup = 23 AND soi.title LIKE '%indian%'
ORDER BY so.time_created DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Generally the ID would be unique across each table, you would not want to name the foreign key with ID if the parent is already ID.

Comment: @krister : How can I add an extra AND to it? I need to do a check on the social_objects table, to know whether the object is enabled. Because I dont want to show inactive contents. WHERE so.subgroup =23 AND soi.title LIKE %indian% . Where should I add *so.active ='yes'*

Comment: @JonH : its returning all the contents that match the search term, irrespective of the subgroup. How to fix it?

Comment: WHERE so.Active='yes' AND so.subgroup=23 AND soi.title LIKE '%indian%'

Answer (score 4):

How are the two tables related?  If they both reference an ID you inner join and use AND to combine conditions:

```
SELECT Parent.ID, Child.ID 
FROM ParentTable 
INNER JOIN ChildTable ON ParentTable.ID = ChildTable.ForeignKeyID 
WHERE Parent.ID = 23 AND Title LIKE '%indian%'
```

Comment: What should be the ForeignKeyID ?

Comment: @user632347 - How do your tables link to one another?  There needs to be a relationship between parent and child table. So you need to be able to take what I wrote and fill in how that relationship exists.  For instance, you have an ID as a primary key in one table, how is that primary key represented in the linked table (as a foreign key generally with the same column name), for instance if I had a users table and a classes table where a user has a class I'd have a UserID and a ClassID in a third table.  The UserID would reference Users Table and ClassID would reference a class table.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SO.ID,SOS.ID 

FROM social_objects SO ,social_objects_single SOS 
WHERE SOS.title LIKE '%indian% and SO.subgroup=23 and SOS.id =SO.subgroup_id`

you should replace the last condition SOS.id =SO.subgroup_id as your tables are connected